# Why does `scroll-behavior: smooth;` not work `<body>`

Tags: html, css

in Chromium 117 I have

```html
<body>
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <a href="#3">3</a>

  <section id="1">
    lorem...
  </section>
  <section id="2">
    lorem...
  </section>
  <section id="3">
    lorem...
  </section>
</body>

<style>
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
</style>
```

Smooth scroll is not working, but if replace `<body>` with `<main>`, or `<div>` or similar, and update the style selectors. it works.

this are the only useragent-stylesheet rules for `<body>`, `<div>`, `<main>` etc are also `display: block;`

```css
    display: block;
    margin: 8px;
```

Comment: it needs to be set on the `<html>`, `<body>` does not work. (this is intended)